# Custom Scroll doesn't work properly on Chrome Mac when doubleclick ad is in Flash

Tags: javascript, jquery, macos, google-chrome, scroll

http://unique-guides.com/fr/vos-microguides

The sidebar of the site above does not scroll properly when the ad underneath is a Flash ad. This works fine in all other browsers (e.g. Mac Firefox, Windows Chrome). It also works fine if the ad is in HTML.

The ad is contained in an iframe, but the same behaviour appears when the ad is in a div.
I am using Chrome 20.0.1132.52.
wmode is opaque, AllowScriptAccess is never

Does anyone have any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just looked at it. change the z-index of #sidebar > .content-holder to something higher than the flash ad (i set it to 200) and it works, must be a bug but there is a workaround

**NOTE** this bug doesn't appear in Chrome for me, but it does in Safari 5.1.6 on OSX

Answer (score 1):

Adding position: relative to #big-box fixed issue in Chrome

Comment: I believe that either yours or AddiktedDesign's answers were the answer. He was just a tad quicker. Thanks a bunch though.